# Decompiling tools for "Old" exe files?

Tags: decompiler

I heard about dnSpy or ILSpy for decompiling .net files.

But how about those files that was NOT written by .net!?

Probably those files previous to XP.

Is there any tools to decompile it to, preferably, C#!?

Much appreciated!

Comment: If they were not written in C#/.NET why would they decompile to .net? Those old files are regular native binaries and you can use any decompiler.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Well, that's the thing, fundamentally they're both Assembly, so  I thought that they should be interchangeable into one another. Maybe I was wrong!?

Comment: Well not really. .NET are IL with a lot of metadata before they get JITed. That's why it's easy to see managed code in tools like dnSpy. After they are JITed they are compiled to native binary and it's no longer a C# code so it's hard to extract it's original C# code at that time.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik So since we know that the non-.net files don't have those metadata and probably AOT, can't we just "make up" those metadata and plug the code in C# into its body!? Just a thought.

Comment: It's an interesting thought. Don't want to diminish the idea but I think it's not possible

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Bummer! But thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Hex Rays decompiler. But you won't get C# code.

- https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/compare_vs_disassembly

Comment: Or any free decompiler...